# How to execute a conditional upsert

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have a table `MyTable` with unique columns `a, b, c` and I need to allow inserting duplicate values for `a` and I want to add a condition only when `MyTable::b == 'b'` then the upsert can be executed like a `WHERE` clause. How can I achieve this with diesel?

```rust
let result = diesel::insert_into(MyTable::table)
        .values(&item)
        .on_conflict(MyTable::a)
        .do_update()
        .set(MyTable::a.eq(&item.a))
        .execute(&connection)
        .unwrap();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want.  Is it that the table should only ever contain at most *one* record with any given values for `(a, b)` and you're saying you want to upsert that record (with the provided value of `c`)?  If so, then your schema requires a uniqueness constraint on the composite `(a, b)` (and probably not on any of the simple columns `a`, `b` or `c`) but it isn't clear from your statement "*I have a table `MyTable` with unique columns `a, b, c`*" exactly what uniqueness constraints already exist?

Comment: @eggyal So when the table `MyTable` is created there's a unique constraint like `UNIQUE(a), UNIQUE(b), UNIQUE(c)` constraint, also there're UniqueViolation error catching, what I want is that when `b` is certain values, I need to allow `a` to have different values

Comment: I think it would help to understand more about the real-world problem that you're trying to model, because the requirements of your schema seem rather peculiar and/or unclear: this very much feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).